# CSV to AWS to DynamoDB on a scheduled basis

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-dynamodb

I am wondering, if possible, to ask your feedback and opinions on the best way to schedule a CSV file to be uploaded on a scheduled basis to DynamoDB.

We have a list of names that is exported from our CRM (the exported CSV list updates every day, if we delete names from our CRM it will shrink)

We receive the CSV file via SFTP on a daily basis, and I was wanting to upload it to DynamoDB to use in our cloud programs. I am very new to AWS services, and new in my workplace here and after some research I thought I could use a flow like:

> AWS Transfer for SFTP -> S3 Bucket -> (Schedule) ->DynamoDB

For the schedule I was thinking of using Data Pipeline or a scheduled Lambda action.

Looking forward to your responses and suggestions, and please let me know if I could provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is already pretty well designed. There is one detail you can still optimize and that's how your AWS Lambda function gets triggered. You mentioned Data Pipeline or a scheduled function invocation, but a better and simpler way would be to use [S3 Events to trigger your AWS Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html). With that you can get your AWS Lambda function triggered for whenever a new object arrives in S3.

If you use AWS SAM to provision your AWS resources there is an example in the SAM Github repository for that use case: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/s3_processor/template.yaml

Comment: Thank you very much Dunedan, I will certainly use the S3 Event to trigger the AWS Lambda function when the new file arrives in S3. I do not know about AWS SAM to provision the resources. Thank you very much for sharing the link and knowledge, and I will learn about it just now.

Regarding the CSV upload to DynamoDB, I have seen a : [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5nuUmlezrHs) using  [Boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3). Do you have any recommendations, or could advise for/against this please?

Comment: Python with boto3 is my preferred combination for AWS Lambda functions and it sounds like it'd fit your use case well as well. While you could use a library abstracting away some details of the interaction with DynamoDB (like PynamoDB) I wouldn't recommend that for your use case, as it's probably more effort to set up and limits your ability to use certain DynamoDB features properly.

Comment: Great, thank you very much Dunedan, I will use Python with boto3.
I sincerely appreciate your help and guidance.